# Can we construct normal ball and normal coordinate at boundary point?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Assume $M$ is a riemannian manifold with boundary and $p\in M.$

When $p$ is interior point,we construct normal coordinate at $p$ like $q=\operatorname{exp}_{p}(x^{i}e_{i})$ and we use $(x^{i})$ as the coordinate of $q.$

In this coordinate we have good property of $g_{ij},\Gamma_{ij}^{k}$.And the geodesic ball is diffeomorphic to the euclidean ball.

However when $p$ is boundary point,can we carry on the above procedure？What do we know about this coordinate？

And how can we understand the geodesic ball in this case？Is it diffeomorphic to the euclidean half ball?I cannot see if this is true.

Any help or reference will be thanked.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by complete in the case of a Riemannian manifold with boundary? The Hopf-Rinow Theorem doesn't hold in this case. Anyway, I don't see the relevance of completeness for building normal coordinates

Comment: @Didier Oh yes,I just omitted the completeness, it's indeed not relevant.

Comment: Just a thought: if the boundary is totally geodesic, then the usual construction works with half a Euclidean ball. If not I have some doubts

Comment: Another thought: the notion of geodesics can be ambiguous in this setting, since it is not the same thing to locally minimize the distance and to be a solution to the geodesic equation. Think of what happens at close boundary points of the complementary of a small spherical cap in the round sphere.

Comment: With a question like this, it is often helpful to study simple examples. Here, I suggest looking at a closed circular disk in the plane and also the complement of an open circular disk. I think the answer becomes fairly clear after that.

Comment: @Deane I don't know why I did not think about disks in the Euclidean plane rather than spherical caps in the sphere: this is so much simpler